# Is the AMD Radeon HD7670M compatible with 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, hardware, radeon, amd-graphics

I want to buy a new laptop and run Ubuntu 12.04 on it. 
I have my eyes on an HP but I want o make sure if the VGA is fully compatible with Ubuntu. The VGA is AMD Radeon HD7670M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You could at least check [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) to see if your card has an available AMD driver.
- Or directly check if your PC is **Ubuntu certified** [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/)
  But note that my laptop HP625 is not listed in this website, but it works fine with 12.04 GNOME Classic.